# Is this line parallel to this plane? If not, find the intersection(can't find my mistake)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I really spent too much time on this number, so help is much appreciated. Is this line parallel to this plane? If not, find the intersection:

Plane:
   \begin{align} x = 2+3r-5s \end{align}
   \begin{align} y = -1+2r+s \end{align}
   \begin{align} z = 3-2r-7s \end{align}

Line:
\begin{align}
  \ \frac{-x+3}{2}=\frac{y}{3}=\frac{z-1}{5} \\\\
\
\end{align}

I started by finding the Cartesian equation of the plane by finding the normal vector with the cross product of r(3;2;-2) and s(-5;1;-7).
I get N(-12;31;13), a normal vector for the plane.
   \begin{align} N(-12;31;13)\end{align} 
After some calculations using the point(2;-1;3), I get this Cartesian equation for the plane:
   \begin{align} -12x+31y+13z+16=0 \end{align}

So far, I'm pretty sure everything is good. Now I have to find if the line is parallel to the plane. One vector of the line is D(-2;3;5). I use the dot product between the normal vector of the plane and the direction vector of the line. If they are perpendicular (0), then the line is parallel to the plane. 
   \begin{align} D(dot)N = 182 \end{align}
Therefore, they are not parallel.
I will convert the line equation from Symmetric to Parametric:
   \begin{align} x=-2t+3 \end{align}
   \begin{align} y=3t \end{align}
   \begin{align} z=5t+1 \end{align}
And I plug the x,y,z inside the Cartesian equation of the plane:
   \begin{align} -12(-2t+3)+31(3t)+13(3t+1)+16=0 \end{align}
I get: t = 7/182.
Then I plug the t inside the parametric equation of the line to find the point of intersection which gives me: 
   \begin{align} x=40/13 y =3/26 z = 31/26 \end{align}
Annnnddd it doesn't work. I've tried tweaking a bit everywhere but nothing works. I know it's a long post, but thank you if you spend some time to help me.

Comment: There could be some typos. First, are the denominators of the line $2,3,5$ or $-2,3,5$?

Comment: If they are $2,3,5$, your answer for $t$ is correct. But the $x$ value is $38/13$.

Comment: Yeah, because the x is negative ((-x+3)/2) so I thought I had to inverse everything. I'll try your answer right now

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks it works :D But I can't upvote you... So the vector for the line is (2;3;5) and not (-2;3;5) even if it's -x?

Comment: Sorry, the vector of the line is indeed $(-2,3,5)$. But the $x$ value is still $38/13$. It didn't really affect the values. :) Another typo is $z=3t+1$ should be $z=5t+1$.

Comment: Right, that was a typo when I wrote it here. I corrected it. So I only made a mistake with the "x". Thank you again, have a nice day.

Comment: I just want to point out that there is no reason to expressing the plane on Cartesian form. You start out with five linear equations with five unknowns and the line is parallel with the plane if there is no solution, intersects if there is exactly one solution and lies in the plane if there are an infinite number of solutions.